During Load Testing StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException
I am getting below RedisTimeoutException. Any idea how to solve?
Timeout performing EXISTS (5000ms), next: EXISTS session:01J2B5BJAP1DHBH9XW0VW8ARF7, inst: 1, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 220, last-in: 529, cur-in: 0, sync-ops: 142, async-ops: 361, serverEndpoint: xxxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, conn-sec: 27.38, aoc: 0, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: xxxxx(SE.Redis-v2.8.0.27420), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=22,Free=32745,Min=1,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=37,QueuedItems=32,CompletedItems=8273,Timers=128), v: 2.8.0.27420 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts) 
I tried to implement Lazy connection
Lazy<IConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<IConnectionMultiplexer>(() => { return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnectionString); }); services.AddSingleton<Lazy<IConnectionMultiplexer>>(lazyConnection);
